# Ember CLI Simple Auth test helper authenticateSession is not defined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am using ember-cli 0.2.6 and ember-cli-simple-auth 0.8.0-beta.2.

Starting from scratch I do the following:

```
ember create project1
//inside project1
ember install ember-cli-simple-auth
```

now i am adding the following line to tests/helpers/start-app:

```
import 'simple-auth-testing/test-helpers';
```

and in environment.js only add this:

```
if (environment === 'test') {
    ENV['simple-auth'] = {
      store: 'simple-auth-session-store:ephemeral'
    };
    ...
}
```

Also I created an acceptance test named "login"

```
ember generate acceptance-test login
```

Which i adjusted to make use of the `authenticateSession();` helper:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import {
  module,
  test
} from 'qunit';
import startApp from 'project1/tests/helpers/start-app';

var application;

module('Acceptance: Login', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    application = startApp();
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('visiting /login', function(assert) {
  authenticateSession();
  ok('yes');
});
```

Now however, whenever i run `ember test` I get the same error message:

```
acceptance/login-test.js: line 22, col 3, 'authenticateSession' is not defined.
```

What did I miss to be not able to access the simple-auth helpers inside my acceptance test? I also tried with the simple-auth 0.7.3 release,... In another try I set up a custom authorizer, but got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the testing helpers like this:

```
import initializeTestHelpers from 'simple-auth-testing/test-helpers';
initializeTestHelpers();
```

Comment: and more important the next line in the documentation. It says: "...and add "authenticateSession" and "invalidateSession" to the "predef" section of tests/.jshintrc."